# Decimal separator and CComVariant

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, variant

Can you specify which decimal separator is used / to be used by CComVariant ?

Context: MSMXML (IXMLDOMElementPtr.getAttribute) always returns us CComVariant initialized with VT_BSTR regardless the attribute type. Therefore we often end up with decimal values stored in a BSTR with '.' as the decimal separator. However when Windows is configured with a coma ',' as the decimal separator, CComVariant is unable to make a conversion to a double or a float.

Example:

```
CComVariant dummy = "1.2345";
dummy.ChangeType(VT_R8);
if(dummy.vt != VT_R8) {
    cout << "Failed to convert" << endl;
} 
else {
    cout << dummy.dblVal << endl;
}
```

When Windows' decimal separator is a coma, we fall in the "Failed to convert". I tried to set `std::locale::global(std::locale("English_United States.1252"))` but nothing changed.

Comment: This is why the VariantChangeTypeEx() function was added.  Note the VARIANT_NOUSEROVERRIDE option.

Comment: Be aware you also have [`_wtof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc25t012.aspx) option.